# return the row and column of the absolute value in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

my question is why doesn't it like the AddressOfMaxRow & AddressOfMaxCol variables? Am I being an idiot?

```
Function MaxABS(rng, AddressOfMaxRow, AddressOfMaxCol, MaxVal)

Dim arr As Variant

arr = rng.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)

    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr(i, j) = VBA.Abs(arr(i, j))
    Next
Next

MaxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(arr)


AddressOfMaxRow = WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(arr), arr, 0)).Cells.Row

AddressOfMaxCol = WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(arr), arr, 0)).Cells.Column

End Function
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Does not like the variables"? Are you getting an error? Is it at compile time or run time?

Comment: 1. Match will not accept a two dimensional array. 2. Index returns a value not a cell and as such does not have a row number.

Comment: Note that all your variables `rng`, `AddressOfMaxRow`, `AddressOfMaxCol`, `MaxVal` including your function `MaxABS` are `Variants`. `i` and `j` are ven not declared. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all variables properly.

Comment: Also, why are `AddressOfMaxRow`, `AddressOfMaxCol`, and `MaxVal` parameters of the function? A `Function` returns something - but you have no assignment statement `MaxABS = ...`

Comment: Also, to get the address of max value inside a range, make sure that max value is the only one. Inside a range, you can have more than 1 cell with max value. What cell would you want to get in that case?

Comment: How would I rectify those lines so that they return the row and col of the maximum absolute value???

Comment: @BigBen If you want to return more than one value with a function you can use `ByRef` parameters for that. So actually you can "return" values through parameters. `ByRef` is default in VBA the opposite is `ByVal`.

Comment: @Peh agreed, wasn't clear if that was OP's intent, I was thinking this would be a UDF. In any case, the approach I took should still be useful in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this, which returns the address (e.g. `$D$9`) of the "max" cell, but can be tweaked to return the row and column as needed.

Note that this assumes that `rng` only contains numeric values and can be beefed up to not error if there's text, for example. It will also only return the first max value address if the max value appears more than once.

```
Function MaxABS(rng As Range) As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = rng.Value

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempMax As Double
    Dim tempRow As Long, tempCol As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = VBA.Abs(arr(i, j))
            If arr(i, j) > tempMax Then
                tempMax = arr(i, j)
                tempRow = i
                tempCol = j
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    MaxABS = rng.Cells(tempRow, tempCol).Address
End Function
```

To return the row and column (separated by a comma since the desired output format was not specified), replace the last line

```
MaxABS = rng.Cells(tempRow, tempCol).Address
```

with the following:

```
With rng.Cells(tempRow, tempCol)
    MaxABS = .Row & "," & .Column
End With
```

with sample output of `9, 4` instead of `$D$9`.